# Работа с областью видимости в JS

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть два файла с кодом, обернутым в анонимную функцию. 
Но второй требует доступ к многим переменным первого.
Какой лучший способ решить проблему? Цель: поменьше глобальных переменных и удобный шаринг данных между файлами.

Я сейчас вижудва варианта: записывать нужные для шаринга переменные в какой-то глобальный обьект или сделать всю анонимную функцио обьектом.

```
(function(){
var a ="value";
})();

(function(){
var iNeedAValue = ???;
})();
```

Comment: в приведенном отрезке кода все переменные локальные и не видим извне никак

Comment: @Grundy именно, но второй блок требует переменных первого.

Comment: без разницы, они не имею доступа к локальным переменным друг друга. никак

Comment: скорее всего вы хотите [что-то вроде этого](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures-module)

Comment: @Grundy, да, там как раз это и обсуждают, спасибо. Но, как я вижу, все сводиться кдобавлению нужных переменных во внешний класс, ну ок.

Comment: почему во внешний класс?

Comment: @Grundy, ну так такие там решения записать нужные для шаринга вещи в глобальный обьект. Ну ок, я примерно так и думал, но мало ли. Было бы хорошо иметь возможность какого-то обьедения двух и бльше глобальных функций в одну, но средства языка не позволяют, как вижу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34427/discussion-between-grundy-and-sss).